# Passing previously retrieved value into webclient head via wizard

Tags: mobile, smartface.io

I would like to pass a session token retrieved initially by a REST GET via web client into the following Webclient REST Actions as a header parameter can this be done through the wizard?

Is there a way to do this in smartface app studio? Any logical idea?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Because you have used WebClient wizard, it generates/configures your WebClient automatically. I can recommend you 2 methods to do this action:

1. Create your WebClient dynamically and go configure it freely/anytime.
2. Create a new WebClient via Wizard and configure it after receiving the token.